# How to use a custom type with array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 6 app, I'm trying to use a custom type to serialize/deserialize a JSONB array

Here my code

```
class CreateAnalyses < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :analyses do |t|
      t.string  :name,           null: false
      t.jsonb   :resources,      null: false, default: []
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class Analysis  < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :resources, ResourceType.new
end


class ResourceType < ActiveModel::Type::Value
  def cast(json_string)
    attribute_hash = JSON.parse(json_string, symbolize_names: true)

    attribute_hash.each_with_object([]) do |attributes, collection|
      collection << Resource.new(attributes)
    end
  end

  def serialize(resources)
    resources.map { |r| r.to_hash.to_json }
  end
end


class Resource
  attr_accessor :from, :to

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    self.from = attributes[:from]
    self.to = attributes[:to]
  end

  def to_hash()
    {
      from: self.from,
      to: self.to
    }
  end
end
```

When I fetch an analysis, the resources are properly cast:

```
<Analysis id: 1, name: "monthly", resources: [#<Resource:0x00007fd60adf05d8 @from=0, @to=10>, #<Resource:0x00007fd60adf05b0 @from=0, @to=10>], created_at: "2019-07-31 14:06:09", updated_at: "2019-07-31 14:06:09">
```

Howver, when I add a resource and I try to save it back to the database, the record is neither updated nor error is raised.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that rails doesn’t know that the attribute changed, so it’s not triggering the dB transaction.

Try adding the following method to your type:

```
def changed_in_place?(raw_old_value, new_value)
  raw_old_value != serialize(new_value)
end
```